# Reference to a plugin

Tags: discussion

When a question or problem arise for a user, is it allowed to reference to a plugin that solves or fulfils the requirements set in the question?

Comment: Have you seen: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/plugin-recommendation-questions-are-off-topic-but-what-about-plugin-recommendat?rq=1

Comment: Now I have, thanks kraftner

Answer (score 2):

I think the current state of things is that asking for a plugin is a bad question, but answering with a plugin is a passable answer.

Still the considerations of "link only" answers apply. Personally I try to formulate it along the following lines: "There is a [plugin] that does [this|something similar], in a [following way], and you might consider using it or studying [source here] as a prior art."

Note that this works best for public plugins. Such answers for commercial plugins are almost always seen and treated as spam.